# does anyone know about the server push/commet technique in gwt

Tags: gwt, push

I need to push some data from server to client in arbitrary manner, i mean when there is data it will push the data in the client widget using commet technique , any idea how and where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with many of these libraries and found that GWTEventService works quite nicely, I have been using it for some time for a web based chat client that I wrote. It is also very easy to get up and running so that might be a good one to start with.

Comment: does it supports multiple tabs in the same browser with the same application and also different browsers at a same time ?

Comment: Sure does. Multiple tabs was an issue in their last stable release though but they did sort this out in their source. The JAR that I am currently using was checked out from the GWT Event Service trunk repos and I built it myself using Maven. Multiple tabs / browsers works nicely here. If you push something to the client it will be received by all tabs / browsers that share that session. I can send the JAR I built if you like.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply i was away in this weekends, i need it from you, i will be greatfull to you if you can send it to me..it seems to be so interesting because in other library jars the multiple tabs are not working perfectly. thanks

Comment: I can mail it to you. Just let me know where you would like me to mail it to (it's about 83k)

Comment: my email is shantuemail(attherate)gmail(dot)com

Comment: If this works for you, please vote for / accept this answer since other's may have a similar request in the future and stumble upon this thread

Comment: yes it works..but why there are 3 of them , specially eventservice-rpc.jar ? what is the difference between them bro ? thanks for the jars..you are also right that this is easy to implement rather than gwt-comet.jar...i waste a lot of time before this..this is also well documented and demo example also very helpful..thanks for your valuable reply on my questions..cheers..

Comment: GWT Event Service is built using Maven so each JAR is basically a separate module within the project. I believe that the rpc JAR is specifically responsible for the code that creates suspended HTTP requests by making rpc calls to the event service servlet that you defined in your web.xml. You can find more details [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/). For your purposes though just make sure you have all 3 in your class path, they need each other.

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries for GWT but here are a few:
http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/
http://code.google.com/p/rocket-gwt/wiki/Comet
http://www.jboss.org/errai
http://code.google.com/p/dwr4gwt/

Descriptions:
http://www.jroller.com/masini/entry/a_comet_implementation_for_google
http://wintermuteblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/websphere-gwt-comet.html

Comment: There are many more, beside you can iplement comet by your self. The idea is well described in the book: Cooper, Collins - "GWT in Practice".

Answer (score 0):

It is a good document about [server push techniques](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ)..